# Making table of key-value pairs

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have two tables one with keys and the other with values. I am joining them to create a table of key-value pairs. Currently I am using a loop. Is there a better way?

```
local keys={"fruit","bread","drink"}
local vals={"apple","french","milk"}

local kv={}
for i=1,#keys do
  kv[keys[i]]=vals[i]
end
```

Comment: Well, under certain circumstances there might be more elegant solutions. For instance, if you are never using the table for individual lookup but are only ever iterating over it, you could instead write an iterator that takes `keys` and `vals` and returns a key and a value without ever creating a third table. If that is your usecase, I could put together an answer. But if you want a generic solution for all possible usages of `kv`, your approach is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Object-oriented programming?

```
-- You could do it in one line too, but this looks neater.
local kv = {fruit = "apple", 
            bread = "french",
            drink = "milk"}

print(kv["fruit"])
print(kv.bread) -- Also works
for index, value in pairs(kv) do --Or you could do it in a for loop
    print("index:", index, "value:", value)
end
```

You would get:

```
apple
french
index:  bread   value:  french
index:  fruit   value:  apple
index:  drink   value:  milk
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't respond to my comment, but here is an answer anyway.

As the others said, your code is fine for a generic use case. Especially, if you want to manipulate `kv` later on or if `keys` and `values` might change later on and `kv` is supposed to be a snapshot of the current state.

In certain situations, there is a more elegant way, though:

If the sole purpose of `kv` is to iterate over it later (as opposed to manipulating it or picking out individual values), then you can write an iterator, that can be used with `for`, like this

```
local keys={"fruit","bread","drink"}
local vals={"apple","french","milk"}:

local function zipkv()
    local i = 0
    return function ()
        i = i + 1
        return keys[i], vals[i]
    end
end


for k,v in zipkv() do
    print("key", k, "value", v)
end
```

The function returned by the iterator `kv` will be called at the beginning of every iteration until the first return value is `nil`. This has the advantage that you don't need to create a third table. You could argue, that instead of a table you are creating a closure, but if you were to iterate over over your `kv` table using `pairs`, then `pairs` is just an iterator creating a closure, too.

Another difference (whether this is an advantage or disadvantage depends on the use case again) is that `zipkv` will always iterate over the current state of `keys` and `vals`. So if you were to change them in after creating the iterator, but before you use the iterator in a loop, you would always zip together the current state of the two tables.

So this is the one case, I can think of, where there is a slightly more elegant (and more efficient) solution to your problem. But it's somewhat restrictive in its applicability, so if you are looking for the "best" general approach, and you've already found it, I'd say.